# Opera browser stopped playing videos

Tags: ffmpeg, codecs, video-player, opera

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 64 bit

A few days ago Opera One (version: 107.0.5045.15) stopped playing videos on multiple sites where videos used to play OK. I have not knowingly made any changes that might have caused this. I get Format not supported or resource unavailable.

Various forum sites proposed linking Chromium video handler to Opera by running:

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libs/libffmpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/lib_extra/libffmpeg.so.32

Which gave:
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/lib_extra/libffmpeg.so.32': No such file or directory

I tried:
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

Which gave:
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/lib_extra/libffmpeg.so.32': No such file or directory

I then tried:
sudo snap install opera

Which gave:
snap "opera" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'

I then tried:
sudo apt install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra

Which gave:
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra is already the newest version (1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu2.22.04.1)

Any suggestions as to how to fix this?

I'm on my limit at this level.

Comment: You can't modify software from snap using `ln` as easily as these from .debs. Even if you can, that's the wrong filepath. You might also want to look in about:flags and about:gpu about:media-internals to see what changed

Comment: that symlink is for the apt version of opera, not the snap. so purge that one, install the apt version and the symlink works. MIND that this in the future likely will break again and needs another fix.

Comment: The new snap from opera works out of the box again.  Using it now on 23.10.